# Short Sum of number theory

Tags: number-theory

Find the sum of all even positive divisors of 1000.

I prime factorised 1000 but the answer was not coming.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried? (This will help you receive answers that actually address your question, and you might have to ask less follow-up questions...)

Answer (score 1):

Try adapting this example for $100$

Since $100=2^2\times 5^2$ you are adding numbers of the form $2^p\times 5^q$. The condition that they are even means $1\le p\le 2$  and we also have $0\le q \le 2$ and each possibility occurs once. The sum is therefore  $$(2+4)\times (1+5+25)=6\times31=186$$

If we list them explicitly by power of $2$ we get $$2+10+50+4+20+100=186$$

Note that I have counted $100$ as a divisor - it is possible that your original question is asking for proper divisors (I would just subtract $100$ at the end).

Note also that $31=\frac {124}4=\frac {125-1}{5-1}$ using the formula for a geometric progression.

Also $6=2+4=1+2+4-1=7-1=\frac{8-1}{2-1}-1$, which represents adding all the factors and then subtracting the odd ones, or $6=2+4=2\times (1+2)=2\times \frac {4-1}{2-1}$ which represents doubling the factors of $50$ (the approach suggested by Awesome).

Comment: @ mark bennet..what is the actual answer then ?? 186 ??

Comment: @soumajitdas If you want all the factors you get $186$, but if $100$ doesn't count, you get just $86$. The mathematical value of this exercise is to see how you can multiply the two parts relating to the primes $2$ and $5$. This approach can be adapted to more complex problems.

Comment: ...you are wrong dude...the answer to my question is 2184..

Comment: @soumajitdas Did you notice that he was explaining for 100 not 1000?

Comment: @soumajitdas $2184=14\times 156$

Answer (score 0):

That is equivalent to finding twice the sum of factors of $500$

Sum of factors of $500=\prod\sum p^i$

$p : $ a prime factor

$i :$ from $0$ to highest power of prime factor in $500$

Comment: this is not a proper answer.please give a proper solution.

Comment: I can also think out that...@ awesome

Comment: This is definitely a legitimate answer on Math:SE. People post hints like this all the time as answers hoping to nudge the OP in the right direction.  If you had ideas already, they belong in the OP so that we know how to best help you.

Comment: @soumajitdas I edited anyways.

Comment: u calculate the answer then...i did it in the same way but the answer came wrong.@ awesome

Comment: Then either you made a calculation error or the answer is wrong. Be confident of what you do. And you can always cross check for small number to see if your method is correct.